# preg_replace double slash issue - php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to add double \ using preg_replace

Code i am using:

```
function escape_sql_regexp( $str ) {
    return preg_replace('/[+*?[\\^\\]$(){}=!|:,]/', '\\\${0}', $str);
}

echo escape_sql_regexp( '(541) 754-3010' );
```

**Outputs:** \(541\) 754-3010
**Expected double slash output:** \\(541\\) 754-3010

Please let me know if its possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you need to add more slashes

```
<?php

function escape_sql_regexp( $str ) {
    return preg_replace('/[+*?[\\^\\]$(){}=!|:,]/', '\\\\\\\\${0}', $str);
}

echo escape_sql_regexp( '(541) 754-3010' );
```

https://3v4l.org/r8pAS